# Agrupando Resultados do Array fora do laço

Tags: php

Como eu Agrupo Resultados do Array fora do laço em uma unica variavel

- No exemplo a baixo o resultado que esta dentro do loop esta correto mais eu preciso que esse mesmo resultado apareça no lado de fora do loop,

Como posso fazer isso funcionar

```
      foreach ($ids_cotados as $value) {
      echo $ids_cotados = $value.','; // 520, 130, 60, 700,

      }
      echo $ids_cotados;   // aqui da erro só pega 520,
```

Comment: vc quer um array ou string no final?

Comment: eu quero que sai assim  520, 130, 60, 700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar algo como `$var = $novo` dentro de um laço o que acontece é a cada volta/iteranção o valor de `$var` será sobrescrito e depois do laço terá o último valor.

Se quer pegar os elementos do array e separa-los por vírgulas pode usar a função `implode()` nesse caso.

```
$arr = array(1,20,30,60,35);
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Saída:

```
1,20,30,60,35
```

Comment: não funcionou.... só mostra "Array"       meu array vem de um post assim Array ( [0] => 520 [1] => 130 [2] => 60 )

Comment: @FabioHenrique poderia colocar na pergunta o `print_r()` de `$ids_cotados` ?

Comment: exatamente print_r()  deu retorna assim Array ( [0] => 520 [1] => 130 [2] => 60 )

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso, a melhor forma é com o `implode()`, ele concatena tudo e coloca uma string no meio de cada valor do array, no caso a `','`, ficaria assim:

```
$stringconcatenada = implode(",", $ids_cotados);
```